# How to delete from a table interlinking 4 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi following are my 4 tables.

> client_parent_question :-

```
+----+------------+------------+---------+-----+------+------+
| id | is_deleted | sort_order | version | cid | pid  | qid  |
+----+------------+------------+---------+-----+------+------+
|  1 |            |          1 |       0 |   1 |    1 |    1 |
|  2 |            |          2 |       0 |   1 |    1 |    2 |
|  3 |            |          3 |       0 |   1 |    1 |    3 |
|  4 |            |          4 |       0 |   1 |    1 |    4 |
|  5 |            |          1 |       0 |   1 |    2 |    7 |
+----+------------+------------+---------+-----+------+------+
```

---

> mysql> select * from client_parent;

```
+----+------------+------------+---------+-----+------+
| id | is_deleted | sort_order | version | cid | pid  |
+----+------------+------------+---------+-----+------+
|  1 |            |          1 |       0 |   1 |    1 |
|  2 |            |          2 |       0 |   1 |    2 |
+----+------------+------------+---------+-----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

> mysql> select * from client_question;

```
+----+------------+---------+-----+------+------+
| id | is_deleted | version | cid | pqid | qtid |
+----+------------+---------+-----+------+------+
|  1 |            |       0 |   1 |    1 |    1 |
|  2 |            |       0 |   1 |    2 |    4 |
|  3 |            |       0 |   1 |    2 |    4 |
|  4 |            |       0 |   1 |    1 |    1 |
|  5 |            |       0 |   1 |    2 |    4 |
|  6 |            |       0 |   1 |    3 |    4 |
|  7 |            |       0 |   1 |    3 |    4 |
|  8 |            |       0 |   1 |    1 |    1 |
|  9 |            |       0 |   1 |    2 |    4 |
| 10 |            |       0 |   1 |    3 |    4 |
| 11 |            |       0 |   1 |    4 |    4 |
| 12 |            |       0 |   1 |    4 |    4 |
+----+------------+---------+-----+------+------+
```

---

> mysql> select * from client_question_option;

```
+----+------------+---------+------+------+
| id | is_deleted | version | cqid | oid  |
+----+------------+---------+------+------+
|  1 |            |       0 |    2 |    1 |
|  2 |            |       0 |    3 |    4 |
|  3 |            |       0 |    6 |    2 |
|  4 |            |       0 |    7 |    3 |
|  5 |            |       0 |   11 |    1 |
|  6 |            |       0 |   12 |    4 |
|  7 |            |       0 |   14 |    1 |
|  8 |            |       0 |   15 |    4 |
+----+------------+---------+------+------+
```

I know only cid and pid of client_parent table

My aim is to delete all from client_question,client_parent_question and client_question_option

In the client_question_option cqid id is the id of client_question table

Following is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c95a3e)

I did

```
DELETE FROM cqo,qo,cpq client_question_option cqo ,client_question cq,client_parent_question ,client_parent cp
WHERE cqo.cqid=cq.id AND cq.pqid=pq.id AND cqo.oid=qo.id AND cq.cid=1  AND cp.pid=1
```

But this did not work.

Comment: Can you alter your tables to include [on delete cascade](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/)?

Comment: @paqogomez Thanks for trying to help.My aim is to do using HQL.So I am first trying using sql and if it works then does for hql.I dont know whether cascading can be done in hql or not

Answer (score 2):

You just need to move the `FROM` keyword after the table aliases. See [multiple-table syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)

```
DELETE cqo, qo, cpq 
FROM client_question_option cqo,
     client_question cq,
     client_parent_question,
     client_parent cp
WHERE cqo.cqid=cq.id AND cq.pqid=pq.id AND cqo.oid=qo.id 
      AND cq.cid=1 AND cp.pid=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `DELETE` query's syntax is wrong, which must be somthing like this:-

```
DELETE cqo,cp,pq 
FROM client_question_option cqo, client_question cq, client_parent_question pq, client_parent cp
WHERE cqo.cqid=cq.id AND cq.pqid=pq.id AND cqo.oid=cp.id AND cq.cid=1  AND cp.pid=1;
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

using inner join

```
DELETE  cqo,cq,cp,pq 
FROM client_question_option cqo 
INNER JOIN client_question cq 
INNER JOIN client_parent_question as pq 
INNER JOIN client_parent cp
WHERE cqo.cqid=cq.id AND cq.pqid=pq.id AND cqo.oid=cqo.id AND cq.cid=1  AND cp.pid=1
```

Comment: A little desciption would have been nice to explain the OP about why you used the inner join.

Comment: @DamienJoe if you define foreign key constraints,then inner join is fast.

Answer (score 0):

You have an option in MYSQL Called as **ONDELETE CASCADE** where in when you set this on a key

example : ***foreign key(cid) references client_parent(cid) ON DELETE CASCADE*** when you delete the key based on your condition all referencing ids will be deleted , so one simple query to delete parent row is enough for it to delete all child rows present in other table data

Advantages of using ON DELETE CASCADE

1. you are not require to right innerjoins and delete data manually
2. you dont get parent key errors
3. you can save up your time

Thats it NJOY!!!